# Private extension galleries error "A connection to the server could not be established [...]"

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, vspackage

Added a private VS extension gallery as described in
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh266746.aspx

using an atom feed as described in
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh266717.aspx

And got this error message:

---

"*A connection to the server could not be established because the following error(s) occurred:*

*Could not determine the protocol used for this gallery. The URL must point to an Atom Feed or SharePoint List configured for hosting Visual Studio Extensions.*

*Please click here to retry the request.*"

---

[This guy](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/8c1ff869-0fd0-4d6a-a31a-f29ad2d4ff59/private-extension-galleries) had the same problem but didn't bother to post his solution (and apparently you can't reply once it's "solved"), so here it goes:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Open up the atom.xml file with Notepad++ then check "*Encode in UTF-8*" under "*Encoding*".
2. In the two places where there's an id after the name of the extension and 2 dots replace that id with the one from your project's *Guids* class. It's the first GUID in there. Alternatively you could open up the vsix file with WinRar / 7Zip and open up the *extension.vsixmanifest* file there (the GUID is found on top of this file).
   **Edit: the 2nd id tag should just include the ID and not the name of the project and the two dots - otherwise [updating the extension won't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20528314/update-private-gallery-atom-such-that-vs-shows-that-an-extension-update-is-avail)**
3. Remove all those hyphens - in the atom.xml file in the case that you copied that from the example in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh266717.aspx

The first GUID on top of the atom.xml file (the one after uuid) can be any GUID you'd like to have (create one under Visual Studio's Tools->Create GUID).